# Overlaying plots with transparent shapes in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a heatmap in ggplot2 that I would like to overlay with a transparent hexagon (so only the outline of the hexagon is visible). The hexagon is drawn using the `ggforce` package. Below is my attempt at this, using some randomly generated data

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

x <- 1:20 
y <- 1:20
data <- expand.grid(X=x, Y=y)
data$Z <- runif(400, 0, 5)

plot <- ggplot(data, aes(X, Y, fill= Z)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  geom_regon(aes(x0 = 10, y0 = 10, sides = 6, angle = 0, r = 2, size=1, color="black", alpha=0)) 
print(plot)
```

However, this generates the plot shown below, which is not what I want (the inside of the hexagon should be transparent).

[image]

How do I generate a transparent shape?

Comment: Move `alpha=0` outside of the `aes()` since you are not mapping it do your data: `geom_regon(aes(x0 = 10, y0 = 10, sides = 6, angle = 0, r = 2, size=1, color="black"), alpha=0)`

Comment: Or set `fill` to `NA`, also _outside_ `aes()`. Same goes for `color` and `size`, by the way.

Comment: @MrFlick answer is working. You should think of putting it as an answer. It will help others to find the answer if they are facing the same problem.